# Linux application in filesystem sandbox

Tags: linux, filesystems, sandbox

Is it possible to install and run applications using the regular filesystem but make created files and changes written to a specific directory?

I want to make an application believe it is installed to the system root and remove it by just deleting one folder from my home directory. A lightweight solution would be great!

Comment: This is not a programming question. Would be better on Superuser or Unix&Linux. I would prefer Unix&Linux, but the migration tool only lets me migrate to Superuser.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/chroot

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup: I don't think he wants a chroot. Chroot requires that he prepares complete environment for the application. But here he wants the application to see the regular environment, just write all changes somewhere else. That can be done with unshare instead.

Comment: A programming solution like a C/Python library for starting the target application would be fine as well. Chroot is no option. I need something lightweight.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at **mbox** http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/mbox/
It intercepts system calls to a temporary directory which you can specify

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible by combining [unionfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) and namespace. Create a mount namespace (using [unshare(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unshare)), mount a unionfs over everything and run the application there (I haven't done it myself, so no example commands, sorry).